# Which of the given options is/are equivalent to the following rule?

Tags: html, css

DIV { line-height: 1.2; font-size: 10pt }

```
a. DIV { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }
b. DIV { line-height: 12em; font-size: 10pt }
c. DIV { line-height: 120%; font-size: 10pt }
d. DIV { line-height: 20%; font-size: 10pt }
e. DIV { line-height: 80%; font-size: 10pt }
```

I think a is correct.

```
a. DIV { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the following two are correct.

```
a. DIV { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }
c. DIV { line-height: 120%; font-size: 10pt }
```

Answer (score 0):

A and C are correct. Please see [`here`](http://latestodesk-test-answer.blogspot.com/2015/01/odesk-css-3-test-questions-and-asnwers.html) for specific details.

Answer (score -1):

So in this question there are two right answers as font-size is same for each case

```css
a. DIV { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }
c. DIV { line-height: 120%; font-size: 10pt }
```

[You can test it here as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)